# Hausdorff topology construction

Tags: general-topology

A Hausdorff space contains at the least two sets $\mathcal{O}_a$ and $\mathcal{O}_b$ who's intersection is empty, that is $\mathcal{O}_a \cap \mathcal{O}_b = \emptyset$, where  $a$ and $b$ are distinct points in a topological space $T$.

> So we consider the set $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, where $a,...,d$ are points.
> Construct a  Hausdorff topology.

Let us construct two neighbourhoods around the points $a,b$, where $a\ne b$, $\exists\ \mathcal{O}_a, \ \mathcal{O}_b \ni \mathcal{O}_a\cap \mathcal{O}_b=\emptyset$ and $a,b \in X$, then we obtain the Hausdorff topological space:

$$X=\Bigl\{\emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,d\} \Bigl\}.$$

However, here $\{a,b\}\cap \{b,d\}=\{b\}$, so it is clearly not empty. Therefore a correct form should be:

$$X'=\Bigl\{\emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\}, \{c\}, \{d\} \Bigl\}.$$

However, I am trying to understand this better. One has to add the union of the sets too, but does one need to add ALL possible unions? Like this:

$$X''=\Bigl\{\emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\}, \{a,d\}, \{a,b\}, \{c,d\}, \{c\}, \{d\} \Bigl\}.$$

or is it sufficient with two unions as such:

$$X'=\Bigl\{\emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\}, \{c\}, \{d\} \Bigl\}.$$

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: A finite Hausdorff space must be discrete.

Comment: @Randall but the points are discrete points, so they are already forming a discrete set.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz that’s not what discrete means here. ‘Discrete’ is an unfortunate word because it is often used in non-precise contexts

Comment: Let me just add that you do indeed have to include all unions of open sets in your topology, that is one of the axioms.

Comment: @MW yes, that is true too, and for a Non-Hausdorff topology has also all possible intersections added too?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz no, that's not what non-Hausdorff means.  non-Hausdorff just means there are two points somewhere that can't be separated with disjoint open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However here we have $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,d\}$ is nonempty

That’s not necessarily a problem. Hausdorff spaces don’t necessarily have *all* open sets mutually disjoint, consider for instance the real line; $(0,2)$ intersects $(1,3)$, but who cares? All we need are *some* disjoint neighbourhoods associated to every pair of distinct points, not *all*.

In this particular case of a finite set, your frustrations in trying to find a Hausdorff topology are not unreasonable; as commented, there is one and only one way to do this, and it’s a bit weird: use the “discrete” topology. This is defined as the topology where *every* set is open. I say ‘weird’ because the intuition of ‘neighbourhood’ falls apart in this case.

To prove this it suffices to show every singleton is an open set (why?). Take some $x\in X$; there are finitely many other $y_1,\cdots,y_n$ in $X$. Take an open neighbourhood $U_j$ of $x$ that does not contain $y_j$, for every $j$: because the intersection is a *finite* one, $\{x\}=\bigcap_j U_j$ is open.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148425/discussion-on-answer-by-fshrike-hausdorff-topology-construction); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.